# Selecting dates with .gt()

Tags: python, pandas, select

I am trying to select the dates where the percentage change is over 1%. To do this my code is as follows:

df1 has `109 rows × 6 columns`

```
`df1['Close'].pct_change().gt(0.01).index` produces:

DatetimeIndex(['2020-12-31', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06',
               '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-11', '2021-01-12',
               '2021-01-13', '2021-01-14',
               ...
               '2021-05-25', '2021-05-26', '2021-05-27', '2021-05-28',
               '2021-06-01', '2021-06-02', '2021-06-03', '2021-06-04',
               '2021-06-07', '2021-06-08'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=109, freq=None)
```

This is not right because there are very few dates which are over 1% but i am still getting the same length of 109 as I would get without `.gt()`.

Could you please advise why it is showing all the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `True` values:

```
df1.loc[df1["Close"].pct_change().gt(1)].index
```

```
>>> df1
            Open  Close
Date
2021-01-01     5      7
2021-01-02     1      3
2021-01-03     1      2
2021-01-04    10      6
2021-01-05     5     10
2021-01-06     6      9
2021-01-07     8      1
2021-01-08     1      3
2021-01-09    10      5
2021-01-10     7      3

>>> df1.loc[df1["Close"].pct_change().gt(1)].index
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-04', '2021-01-08'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

Comment: It just produces the entire df for me.

Comment: Is it what you expect with the sample?